# Bluetooth Dual LE and Classic Mode Flags

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

In the Advertising section of a BLE, The Bluetooth SIG Define the "Flags"

which has these plus a few more.

- BR/EDR Not Supported
- Simultaneous LE and BR/EDR to Same Device Capable (Controller)
- Simultaneous LE and BR/EDR to Same Device Capable (Host)

I am having an issue on a CSR chipset design that does not support GATT over BR/EDR.

Apple works great, as it always connects to LE.

..but android devices persistently try to connect GATT over BR/EDR if the audio is already up; therefore fail because CSR cant handle BR/EDR transport for GATT.

I am thinking these flags are at the core of the problem.

In CSR's demo code they do not set "any" of the above flags.  I have had limited success with my problem on some handsets by setting the "Not Supported" flag.

The issue is the other two flags. How does Controller/ Host relate to other LE terms.  For example Central/Peripheral or later Master/Slave.

I dont know what flags to set for my use case.  Any suggestions welcome?

Comment: BR/EDR Not Supported does not really help. As soon as Android notices that there is also the second channel it seems to ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Static Random address for all LE operations. That way the Android device thinks it's a different device than when talking over Bluetooth Classic since that uses the public BD_ADDR.

Or, one variant of the `connectGatt` takes a `transport` parameter which you can set to `TRANSPORT_LE` to force communication over BLE.

If your device supports BLE and BR/EDR at the same time you should set these flags:

```
BR/EDR Not Supported=0
Simultaneous LE and BR/EDR to Same Device Capable (Controller)=1
Simultaneous LE and BR/EDR to Same Device Capable (Host)=1
```

If the flag data is missing completely, it's the same as if all fields are zero.

Comment: Thanks, I would like to understand what the 'Host' and 'Controller' parts mean in this context.

Comment: Normally you have a Bluetooth controller on an external chip and then a host computer (to which you have the chip plugged in). I think the idea is that the first flag (controller) is whether the Bluetooth chip itself supports both, and the second if the software on the host supports handling both simultaneously.

Comment: might be a old, but if BR/EDR not supported bit is set to 0, it basically means that BR/EDR is indeed supported? @Emil

Comment: Yes, since inverted logic.